# How to pass data from javascript to php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I don know javascript well, but I need to do something as soon as possible.
I have such JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example-2').ratings(5).bind('ratingchanged', function(event, data) {
    $('#example-rating').text(data.rating);
  });
});
```

I need to use the result of this function in php. Can you please tell me how?
Thanks.

Comment: Google Search `Jquery AJAX`

Comment: you can pass it with ajax only.

Comment: Have you tried using the search function? This one was asked a dozen times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery includes a library that makes ajax calls very simple, example below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example-2').ratings(5).bind('ratingchanged', function(event, data) {
    $('#example-rating').text(data.rating);

    $.ajax({
        url : 'page.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : { rating : data.rating },
        success : function(response){
            console.log("successfull");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

On the PHP side, you can pick it up with:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    echo $_POST['rating'];
}
```

[jQuery.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Yeah, and can someone tell me how to do this in wordpress?